# one liner to get memory usage

Tags: shell-script, memory

Looking to do a one liner to tell the total amount of free memory on system including swap and cache.

`free -t` isn't an option so I have to do a sum of the values under the free column.

I'm not sure how I can get the values; if I use `awk`, how can I reference different numbers in different lines (free `Mem` is `$3`, whereas the free swap space for example on a different line is `$4`)?

Comment: Don't know why you want include buffers/cache in memory, you shouldn't count this (indeed total row doesn't count) because is you sum used+free of cached/buffers row, it's equal to total RAM. So the only sense to measure is Mem and Swap rows, and that is what Total row do. ¿?

Comment: fair enough but i want to include them for my script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the debian I have in front of me right now, `free -t` shows a `Total:` row:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8197980    2583348    5614632          0     222508    1904352
-/+ buffers/cache:     456488    7741492
Swap:      7807584          0    7807584
Total:    16005564    2550180   13455384
```

If you just need that row, you could use `tail` and `awk` to grab the values.

However, if your `free` does not show this row, you could use awk with `RS=""` to join the lines:

```
free | awk -v RS="" '{print $10 "+" $17 "+" $21}' | bc
```

If the column layout of your `free` is different to mine, you may have to fidget with the field numbers.

Explanation:
The `RS` field is the record separator. Setting this to `""` joins all the lines in the output of free, so `awk` can reference them as if they were on one 'line'.

Counting from the beginning, `$1` to `$6` are the column headers, `$7` is the `Mem:` row header, `$8` to `$10` are the values on that row... Therefore `$10` is the free memory value. This is done in a similar way for the following values;

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            $8         $9        $10        $11        $12        $13
-/+ buffers/cache:        $16        $17
Swap:          $19        $20        $21
```

The awk command `{print $10 "+" $17 "+" $21}` basically joins these values with a `+` in between, and the output is piped to `bc` to calculate the sum.

Comment: can you explain this code please? and also can you show output of free and explain what $10 etc is referring to ?

Comment: Since I can't yet comment on @user1717828's answer, I'll have to do it here. The problem with using just `awk '{print $3}' is that the '+/- cache' row label includes a space and therefore `$3` on that row is the `used` column, not the `free` one.

Comment: yep i agree , that is one of my issues

Comment: @plonk, thanks!  I was scratching my head on that.  I updated the answer.  Out of curiosity, why couldn't you comment on my answer?

Comment: @user1717828 I don't have enough reputation for that yet :(

Comment: @johndoe12345 I updated my answer and added some explanation.

Comment: @plonk, That's retarded.  Have an upvote.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation . i understand whats happening and my value locations are the same as yours (Linux Mint). however my result is much different. free -t says total is 2785828 but the script shows 4273984

Comment: ok i did the command without the sum and the values are defo right. any idea where the free -t command gets it values ? i think it seems to add free mem and swap but not cache ?

Comment: @johndoe12345 from the [source code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/free.c) of procps-ng's free, it seems that it only uses free mem and free swap (line 410):
    `printf(" %11s", scale_size(kb_main_free + kb_swap_free, flags, args));`

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run `free` and then parse the output, like

```
free | awk '{print $4}' | tail -3 | sed '2d' |paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: @johndoe12345 Let me know if you're able to run it. If so, I will explain the line piece by piece.

Comment: yep . am able to run that but the value i get doesnt match the total if i run free -t

Comment: @johndoe12345 I added a note - the free memory will change each time you run the program (the computer is doing stuff, after all).  Run `free -t` twice in a row really fast.  It still changes, right?

Comment: yes i am aware of that but the numbers i get are very different so not matching up

Comment: and your $3 above is not free on all lines,in other words $3 on line w is 989180 when it should be 7300468

Comment: @johndoe12345, Wow, sorry about that.  As @plonk pointed out, the top row of `free` is one column shifted.  Does the new syntax work?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this could be an alternative to `free`

`cat /proc/meminfo | grep -e MemFree -e Buffers -e SwapFree | gawk 'BEGIN{s=0}{s+=$2}END{print s}'`

Comment: have to use free